# angular-ui typeahead, not dismiss after click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

angular-ui typeahead, not dismiss after click, my requirement is I will have a checkbox in the typeahead result, and support multi select, so I don't want the typeahead popup dismiss when I click one of them, I tried to change the typeahead code, but not perfect.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Angular UI typeahead is quite simplistic and doesn't really support multi-select, so you might be better off using the Angular-UI Select2 directive instead, as it supports multi-select as standard.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2